# Some characters like ϕ not getting compiled to pdf

Tags: xetex, greek

I have been struggling to show the character 'ϕ' to show up in my compiled PDF. It happens with some greek letters, but some get compiled. Is there any specific font family or package to use to help resolve this issue?
I am using Xelatex to compile.

Here is a minimal example to demonstrate this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{alphabeta}
\title{Greek Letters}
\author{aakashguptachoudhury }
\date{November 2019}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
There is a theory which states that if ever anyone discovers exactly what
the Universe is for and why it is here, it will instantly disappear and be
replaced by something even more bizarre and inexplicable.

There is another theory which states that this has already happened.

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1.7]{universe}
\caption{The Universe}
\label{fig:universe}
\end{figure}

\section{Phi Phi}
Phi - ϕ

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

Comment: 1. Welcome! 2. Do not post links to codes, post the code. 3. Use `$\phi$`.

Comment: Thanks. But how to render that particular character without defining it as such? Actually I am compiling latex written by others to pdf, and can't tell them to use $\phi$ everywhere instead of ϕ

Comment: Welcome to the site! Glad you solved your problem. In the future, with more difficult questions, it’ll be a lot easier to reproduce the problem and help you if we can compile the MWE for ourselves. Because of the graphic (which isn’t related to your problem), we can’t. Something to keep in mind next time.

Comment: By the way, you don’t need `inputenc`, and you are probably getting warnings to remove it LuaLaTeX and XeTeX take UTF-8 input natively, and `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` has been the default for other engines since 2018.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. I got the answer. Since, the default font does not support all greek letters, I had to use something like:-

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
```

Comment: You should add `\tracinglostchars=2` near the top of your document, and you’ll get a warning message whenever that happens. By default, the warning is silently buried in the middle of your `.log` file.